# Quantum Harmonic Oscillator With a Sudden Change in Electric Field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, harmonic-oscillator

Consider the following hamiltonian:
$$H=\begin{cases}
    \frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega_0^2x^2,&\text{ for }t<0\\
    \frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega_0^2x^2-q\epsilon_0x,&\text{ for }t>0
    \end{cases}$$
I want to find the probability that  the particle will remain in the ground state for time $t > 0$. Denote the ground state for $t<0$ at $|0\rangle$ and the ground state for $t>0$ as $| 0'\rangle$. This can then be done in the $x$ basis by doing some translations of $\psi'(x)=\langle x|0'\rangle$ for $t>0$ then finding that $\psi'(x)=\psi(x-a)$ for a constant $a\in\mathbb{R}$ in terms of the other constants in the equation, from there you can find:

$$|\langle 0'|0\rangle |^2=\left|\int_\mathbb{R}\psi(x-a)^*\psi(x)dx\right|^2$$

This all makes pretty good sense to me, but what I can't figure out is why this couldn't be done with a regular complex dot product in the Energy basis since that isn't a continuous spectra. What am I missing here?

Comment: The expansion of your shifted state in energy eigenstates is messy.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero how would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

following the discussion with the OP:

Basically you are right - we just need a transformation from one basis to another. Namely, from the eigenstates of $H$ before the turning on of the field to the eigenstates of $H$ after. Let's call them $H$ and $H'$ for convenience, and their respective eigenstates $|n\rangle$ and $|n'\rangle$. As you notice, this transformation is achieved by a unitary matrix $U$, that relates the expansion coefficients in one basis $|\psi \rangle = \sum_n a_n |n\rangle$ to the expansion coefficients in another basis $|\psi \rangle = \sum_{n'} a_{n'} |n'\rangle$. So $a_{n} = \sum_n U_{n, n'} a_{n'}$. It is easy to see that the coefficients are the overlap between the basis states, as $U_{n, n'} = \langle n | n' \rangle$. To see this, just apply it to a basis set $|n'\rangle = \sum_{n} U_{n, n'} |n\rangle$ and enter the unit operator $\sum_{m}|m\rangle \langle m|$ to get
$$ \sum_{m}|m\rangle \langle m|n'\rangle = \sum_{n}U_{n,n'}|n\rangle $$
which from the orthogonality of the basis state will give you $U_{n,n'} = \langle n | n'\rangle$. This overlap is exactly the integral over the two wave functions.

However, the integral is not the only way to calculate the overlap. As you noted, the basis of $H'$ can be obtained from the basis of $H$ by a translation in $x$. This translation can be written as an operator
$$T_{x_0} = e^{-ipx_0/\hbar} = e^{\sqrt{\frac{m \omega}{2\hbar }}x_0(a-a^{\dagger})} = e^{-\frac{m \omega x_0^2}{4\hbar }}e^{-\sqrt{\frac{m \omega}{2\hbar}}x_0a^{\dagger}}e^{\sqrt{\frac{m \omega}{2\hbar }}x_0a}$$
so for the ground state the overlap is given by
$$\langle 0' | 0 \rangle = e^{-\frac{m \omega x_0^2}{4\hbar }} \langle 0 |e^{-\sqrt{\frac{m \omega}{2\hbar }}x_0a^{\dagger}}e^{\sqrt{\frac{m \omega}{2\hbar }}x_0a} |0 \rangle = e^{-\frac{\hbar m \omega x_0^2}{4}}$$
where we used the fact that $a|0\rangle = 0$ so only the zeroth term in the power expansion of the exponent can contribute

Comment: I still don't see why we cant just calculate $U$ explicitly?

Comment: how would you calculate them explicitly other than the integrals or using the translation operator? this is the calculation

Comment: By evaluating $U_{n,n'}=\langle n|n'\rangle$?

Comment: yes, which is the integral (or $\langle m | T_{x_0} | n \rangle$, same thing). These are numbers that you have to calculate directly, in some manner, and they represent the overlap between the states. They are inherently dependent on the Hamiltonian

Comment: why is that an integral though? $|{n}\rangle$ is a discrete spectra, and we know what the energy eigenvalues of bot $H$ and $H'$ are since $H'$ is just a translation, so I don't see why we cant find $U$ just from that information

Comment: you can, this amounts to the other way I wrote $\langle m' | n\rangle = \langle m| T_{x_0} | n\rangle$ but this is not an easy calculation to do in general. The ground-state is a special case (it is easy to calculate for coherent states, though)

Comment: So in this case $U$ is $T_{x_0}$? How did you get that?

Comment: hint: calculate $T_{x_0}HT^{\dagger}_{x_0}$ (e.g. using Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff) and find out for which value of $x_0$ you get $H' = T_{x_0}HT^{\dagger}_{x_0}$. From this you can show that if $|n\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $H$ with eigenvalue $n$, then $T_{x_0}|n\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $H'$ with the same eigenvalue

Comment: But where did you get $T_{x_0}$?

Comment: Nevermind I see where $T_{x_0}$ is coming from. I still don't see why $U=|n'\rangle\langle n|$ doesn't just equal the identity though. In the $H$ basis $|n\rangle$ is just a column vector of all $0$'s except a $1$ in the $n$th in the position, so is that we we would need $\langle n'|$ in that same basis to calculate $U$?

Comment: How did you get the second equality in your the translation line? It seems that that first term exponential term doesn't belong there

Comment: @ChristopherQuinnLaFondJr. see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Special_cases under "Special Cases"

Answer (score 0):

Since the change is sudden, We can assume
$$|\Psi(0)\rangle =|0\rangle $$
You can expand this in $|n'\rangle $ basis of the electric field applied Hamiltonian.

$$|\Psi(0)\rangle =\sum_n |n'\rangle \langle n'|0\rangle  $$
For any later time $t>0$, this would be
$$|\Psi(t)\rangle =U(t)|\Psi(0)\rangle =\sum_n e^{-iE_{n'} t/\hbar}|n'\rangle \langle n'|0\rangle $$
Now find the transition amplitude,
$$P(0\rightarrow 0',t)=\left|\sum_n e^{-iE_{n'}t/\hbar} \langle 0'|n'\rangle \langle n'|0\rangle \right|^2$$That's it.

Comment: just to finish this off: the point is that the sum in the last line is exactly the integral OP got: $|\sum_{n'} \exp(-iE_{n'}t/\hbar)\langle 0' | n' \rangle \langle n' | 0\rangle |^2 = |\langle 0' | 0 \rangle |^2 = |\int \psi^*_{0'}(x)\psi_{0}(x) dx|^2$

Comment: @yyy why does that reduce to the same integral? Since $|0\rangle$ should look like a column vector with a $1$ in the first entry and $0$'s for the rest shouldn't we able to just calculate this explicitly?

Comment: @ChristopherQuinnLaFondJr. in order to calculate it explicitly you need the basis transformation rules between the basis which is composed of the eigenstates of $H$ before the sudden change and $H$ after the sudden change - they are different operators so they imply different basis. The basis transformation rules are exactly these integrals $\langle n' | m \rangle = \int dx \psi^{*}_{n'}(x)\psi_m(x)$

Comment: @yyy Sakurai says that for a non continuous spectra you can change the basis using the Unitary operator $U=\sum_k|b^{(k)}\rangle\langle a^{(k)}$ and that then we have that $b^{(k)}=Ua^{(k)}$, so why couldn't we construct $U$ then use that to switch to the $|n'\rangle$ and then find the amplitude using $|\langle 0'|U|0\rangle|^2$?

Comment: @ChristopherQuinnLaFondJr. what are the components of this $U$, do you think? how would you write them, in bra-ket formulation, for example?

Comment: @ChristopherQuinnLaFondJr. btw there is one other way to calculate them, and that is to notice that the change in basis is equivalent to a translation by $a$, which we can represent using the exponent of creation and annihilation operators. if you're interested I can elaborate on that in a separate answer

Comment: @yyy that's kind of what I was asking, naively I'd say that the components are just $\sum_k |n'^k\rangle \langle n^k|$ but that feels like it would just give the identity.

Comment: @yyy I would love to see that